# Flutter Image Picker Stuck On Camera

Tags: ios, flutter, imagepicker

I use the plugin https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

> image_picker: ^0.8.0+3

on android the code runs fine on some devices, but when installed on ios, but when taking pictures with the camera, the application is stuck on the camera display

i using i phone 5 and i phone 10, but both stuck on camera display,
Button "Retake" and "Use Photo" cant click

[image]

here is my code

```
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(
             maxWidth: 800,
             imageQuality: 85,
             source: ImageSource.camera,
           );
           if (pickedFile != null) {
             dPrint('Original path: ${pickedFile.path}');
             String dir = path.dirname(pickedFile.path);
             var timeStamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
             var fileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp.toString() + ".jpg";
             String newPath = path.join(dir, fileName);
             File newFile = await File(pickedFile.path).copy(newPath);

             if (newFile != null) {
               print(newFile);
             }
           }
```

Flutter doctor result :

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64, locale en-ID)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

> ```
> Flutter 2.0.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> Framework • revision 60bd88df91 (3 months ago) • 2021-03-03 09:13:17 -0800
> Engine • revision 40441def69
> Tools • Dart 2.12.0
> ```

Comment: please add device detail(name, model), `flutter doctor` result and image_picker lib version

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan I have added it, please help

Comment: please confirm your dart version. run `flutter --version`

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan  I have added it

Comment: it is working perfectly on my side. dart version 2.12, device Iphone7 (OS 14.3), and ImagePicker 0.8.0

Comment: I am not able to reproduce it.

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan I tried it on my friend's cellphone which has an iPhone 8, "use photo" button can click and work perfectly, but on phone 5 and 10 it doesn't work :(

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues

Comment: create the issue here, since the behavior is not uniform across difference devices

Answer (score 0):

You need to tap on `Use Photo` to get the image captured

Comment: "Use photo" and "Retake" cant click :(

Comment: They should be clickable. re-check your imagePicker IOS configuration

Comment: I've added keys to Info.plist as mentioned in the documentation, but the two buttons still can't be clicked